# cocos2D automatic moving image

Tags: iphone, image, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Everything looks fine, I have no errors, yet, when I run the program it crashes. Please help, I'm getting frustrated. Here's what I have:

```
-(id) init {

if( (self=[super init])) {


    homeCloud1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"homeCloud1.png"];
    homeCloud1.position = ccp(140,200);
    [self addChild:homeCloud1];


    [self schedule:@selector(callEveryFrame)];


    }

return self;
}



-(void) callEveryFrame: (ccTime) dt {

homeCloud1.position = ccp(homeCloud1.position.x +20*dt, homeCloud1.position.y);
if (homeCloud1.position.x > 480+30) {
    homeCloud1.position = ccp(-30, homeCloud1.position.y);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cant say for sure, post your crash log but there is one error I see

```
[self schedule:@selector(callEveryFrame)];
```

needs a colon

```
[self schedule:@selector(callEveryFrame:)];
```

Comment: Even if I am not passing it any parameters?

Comment: Oh, an I found the issue, my background was covering the sprite. If I remove the background it works fine, do you have an idea on how I can have my background behind the moving sprite? Thanks.

Comment: use the z order [self addChild:backGround z:-1];

Comment: But for the other issue you could use [self scheduleUpdate] and then implement -(void)update:(ccTime)dt to do your update stuff

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what that last comment means. Hahah, I'm really new to this, and I'm only 16. :p In Lamen's terms, could you repeat that? Sorry again.

Comment: instead of using your callEveryFrame method rename it -(void)update:(ccTime)dt and use  [self scheduleUpdate] to call it, pretty much the same as what you're doing but it's built in to cocos2d

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for all your help! My app menu is looking great now! :D